# Shouldn't this code crash

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

```
int *p;
while(true)
{
 p = new int;
}
```

Due to running out of memory space, shouldn't this code crash. I have tried printing out the value of p, that is the address of memory located for p, and it seems to increase yet there is no crashing.

Why is this so?

Comment: Well, this stuff doesn't happen instantly. And for such a small allocation, you'll be waiting a looooong tiimmme.

Comment: No, it shouldn't really crash. Eventually `new` should throw an exception and terminate the program, though. Depending on your system, maybe after a few billion loops - don't hold your breath on a 64 bit system with plenty of swap space. Try watching the memory use of the program using task manager / ps / whatever. If it's going up, you'll see how fast.

Comment: Are you running on a 64 bit OS maybe?

Comment: depends on definition of 'crash'. It should forcibly terminate due to uncaught exception

Comment: If you are using the nothrow version of new it will never crash since when it runs out of memory it will just return null (which from your code snippet does not appear you are calling, just wanted to mention it, if you have #defined new to (nothrow) new then it will never crash)

Comment: Actually I am running on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: new will allocate more than 32 bytes for this, but even if it allocated 64 bytes per iteration it will take 33,554,432 to hit the 2GB memory boundary on your 32 bit machine. If you really want this to die you need to use the suggested loop iterations below where you allocate arrays of integers.

Comment: If your system pages, wouldn't it just page the memory, so I think you'd have to wait for several gigs.

Comment: @baash05 - It may page if the RAM is not available, but a 32 bit application only gets 2GB even if the system has more (although in MS land and I would assume in *nix land as well, there are compiler extensions that can exceed that).
Also just realized I had done bad math yesterday, since you are declaring an int it will not allocate 32 bytes, on most modern compilers that will be 32 bits, 4 bytes, which even if it allocates it with twice the space (new adds some data so the memory can be deleted later) at 8 bytes you are looking at 268,435,456 loop iterations before you hit 2 GB.

Comment: As a general rule, relying on something to "crash" as evidence of a fault is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution is like trying to crash a car at a telephone pole down the street while driving 1MPH.  It will happen eventually but if you want fast results you need to up the speed a bit.

```
int *p;
while (true) { 
  p = new int[1024*1024*1024];
}
```

My answer though is predicated on your code base using the standard STL allocator which throws on a failed memory allocation.  There are other available allocators which simply return `NULL` on a failed allocation.  That type of allocator will never crash in this code as the failed allocation is not considered fatal.  You'd have to check the return of the allocation for `NULL` in order to detect the error.

One other caveat, if you're running on a 64 bit system this could take considerably longer to crash due to the increased size of the address space.  Instead of the telephone poll being down the street, it's across the country.

Comment: I get the picture, but even as I type this comment, there is no crash.

Comment: @Gunner, that's very odd.  Are you using the standard STL throwing allocator?

Comment: good question, I mentioned that in the comments above, if you are using the nothrow version of new then you need to check when new returns null, at that point throw your own exception. The nothrow version of new will return a null pointer rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: You may speed it up on 64 bit systems with virtual memory overcommit by going through each byte you allocate and writing to it, to make sure it isn't using a copy on write page of zero's. ie. limited by physical RAM not by address space.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The program actually caused a hang. I got more than I bargained for. Larger amount of allocation at a time did the trick. I wouldn't advice anyone to try it out on Windows XP, I had to reboot :).

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you won't close this question until you see a crash :)

On Unix like operating system you can restrict the amount of virtual memory available to a process using the [**ulimit**](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) command. By setting the VM to 1MB I was able to see the desired results in about 5 seconds:

```
$ ulimit -v $((1024*1024)) # set max VM available to process to 1 MB

$ ulimit -v                # check it.
1048576

$ time ./a.out             # time your executable.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted

real    0m5.502s
user    0m4.240s
sys  0m1.108s
```

Answer (score 7):

Sseveral allocations of small chunks of memory is slower than one big allocation. For instance, it will take more time to allocate 4 bytes 1 million times, than 1 million bytes 4 times.

Try to allocate bigger chunks of memory at once:

```
int *p;
while(true)
{
 p = new int[1024*1024];
}
```

Comment: That's a little misleading. Memory allocation of small objects is no slower than large objects. It just takes more iterations to run out of memory using small allocations.

Comment: @Ferruccio Indeed. I'll try to rephrase

Answer (score 4):

You did not wait long enough.

[If you want to see how it's progressing, add some output on every 1000000 loops, or something like that.  It **will** fail eventually.]

Comment: I actually tried outputting the value of p, that is the address of memory p points to and I found it to increase.

Comment: @Gunner - yes, I had in mind a coarser grain metric so you can see roughly how long it's taking to grow. Once you hit the pagefile, it will slow right on down.  @Steve Jessop's suggestion in comments to use a process monitor is a good bet for this though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that the compiler is doing some optimization and does not really allocate memory.
I ran the above examples (using valgrind) some times and saw that even though there where allocations, all where of 0 bytes memory.

Try this and your program will get killed (at least on unix):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

int *p;

while (true) {
        p = new int[1024*1024];
        p[0] = 0;
        printf("%p\n",p);
        for(unsigned j = 1; j < 1024*1024; j++) {
                p[j] = p[j-1] + 1;
        }
}

return 0;
}
```

You see the only difference is that I use the allocated memory.

So, it doesn't really crash because I guess the OS is preventing the process from crashing by just killing it (Not 100% sure about this)

Comment: Interesting answer. How long does it take for your code to crash?

Comment: I was trying out on windows. Even allocating 1024*1024*1024 at a time didn't cause a crash for some time. I guess there must have been some kind of optimization.

Comment: I also tried 1024*1024*1024 = 2^30, but I got a segmentation fault after trying to use it :) I guess the reason is that no such block of memory existed on the machine. ---------------- . The most reasonable explanation is that the compiler optimizes this out. Try keeping all allocated blocks and use them after the while loop to do some computations or something to prevent the compiler from optimizing this out. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: most OSes will perform optimistic allocation. When you malloc, say, 500 MB, that memory may not actually be reserved until your program actually attempts to read or write to it.

Linux in particular is notorious for over-promising memory and then relying on the OOM (out-of-memory) killer to whack processes that try to collect on the kernel's promises.

Comment: This maybe a possible reason, but is it really the case that OS will only promise for memory and then provide it when actually needed?

Comment: @Gunner: under at least some systems, configurations, and virtual memory states, yes. There's a good write-up of an example in Linux at http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html